# Debugging rspec using RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm unable to debug rspecs from RubyMine. I created a debug configuration, but when I run it I get an error on the first line in my spec

`require 'spec_helper'`

`Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- spec_helper`.

I'm able to run this same spec from my command line without error with this command: `rspec /Users/me/git/myproject/spec/models/myspec_spec.rb`

Any ideas what could be different between running the `rspec` command from RubyMine vs the command line, which could cause this error?

[image]

Edit:

The full exception trace:

```
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- spec_helper
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Users/me/git/myapp/spec/models/myspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta6/bin/rdebug-ide:187:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you have a `spec_helper.rb` in your `spec` folder?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari yes i do

Comment: Do you have `require spec_helper` in `rails_helper`? and then in `.rspec`, what is there?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari, hi, i'm not sure what you're asking, the .rsepc file is in my ruby-2.5.1/gems.... When running from RubyMine the exception occurs on the first line of `myspec_spec.rb`. I get the exact same exception if I run `rspec` from the wrong directory, `rspec ./models/myspec_spec.rb`. But the test runs correctly if I run it from the project base directory: `rspec ./spec/models/myspec_spec.rb`

Comment: I have a `.rspec` in my project root dir. It has this line `-r rails_helper
`. In turn, `rails_helper` has `require spec_helper` in it. The later part is generated and done for you when you install rpsec: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails .

Comment: I think you are using the global `rspec`. You should bundle install in your project root and then `rails generate rspec:install`.

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari thanks, I did this. I now have an `rspec` in my project root which contains `require spec_helper`, and I have a `/spec/rails_helper.rb` that contains `require 'spec_helper'`. But I have the same exception (i added the full exception trace to the original question)

Comment: Maybe look into this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-gemsets.html

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari i deleted my `.idea` folder and re-opened the project in RubyMine. Everything works great now. thanks for the help